# N1ql query to handle datetime scenario

Tags: couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I am having a scenario where I need to fetch all records from students document :

```
  "fname": "abc",
  "timeOfAdmission": 1576042885166,
  "lname": "rawat",
  "studentId": "1"
```

where studentId is our documnetId.

Is it possible using N1ql to execute a query like this

```
select * from students where (CurrentTime - timeOfAdmission) > 3600000.
```

where CurentTime, timeOfAdmission and  3600000 is in milliseconds.

How can we write this query using N1ql ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use date functions https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html#fn-date-now-millis

```
SELECT s.*
FROM students AS s
WHERE s.timeOfAdmission <  NOW_MILLIS() - 3600000;

CREATE INDEX ix1 ON students(timeOfAdmission);
```